# Autocorrelation differences

Tags: regression, interpretation, autocorrelation

Though I know the key definition of autocorrelation. How can I define the difference of autocorrelation in case of simple regression model and multiple regression model?

Answer (score 0):

"Difference of autocorrelation" doesn't make sense. Did you mean "autocorrelation of difference" ? You might want to look at http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf as an introduction to "regression versus time series" suggesting a way to integrate both memory(arima) and regression (x) effects. You might want to find Mr. Chitra Baniya in Katmandu , Nepal [Central Department of Botany, Tribhuvan University] as he might be of help to you as you pursue this subject.